# Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'handsontable'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, handsontable

I am using [Hands on table](https://github.com/warpech/jquery-handsontable) plugin for implementing excel like table. My issue is little bit strange. In my javascript code i am calling this plugin on a div element in document.ready event like :

```
 $("#vdcontainer").handsontable({
        startRows: 2,
        startCols: 1,
        colHeaders: ["<span style='font-size:15px; font-weight:bolder; width:500px; text-align:center;'>Enter variable data here Or just cut & paste</span>"],
        minSpareRows: 1
    });
```

Now upto this point every thing is going perfect plugin creates an excel like table inside div whose id is `vdcontainer`. Now the problem occur when i clicked over a button and when i called this plugin from the handler function of click event, like this :

```
$("#vdcontainer").handsontable('loadData', ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']);
```

Now it shows me following error message on console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'handsontable'
```

Can anybody have any idea why the call to handsontable function is working fine on document.ready event and not working in event handler function in the same js file ?

Comment: Are you including the `handsontable` file?

Comment: yes i included that's why it was working in document.ready

Comment: It seems to works initially because it creates the excel like table inside the div. The error occurs only when call it from inside the event handler function.

Comment: Does the click handler run after all your Javascript files are loaded?

Comment: Are you creating the `vdcontainer` element dynamically? It sounds like something may have removed the element after the handsontable was initialized, then added it back later without attaching the table again.

Comment: Also: are you sure you're not accidentally including jQuery twice? (The second time after running `.ready()` handlers, but before click handlers execute.) In this case, the second "instance" of jQuery wouldn't have the plugin initialised.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle showing the problem, or provide a link to your site with the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your included version of jQuery probably to old - The handsontable plugin requires jQuery 1.7+ due to the use of .on.